# How do I save after editing a file in terminal using Vi in Edubuntu?

Tags: apache2.4, vi

In page it says in order to solve a problem in Apache 2.4, we have to create a configuration file inside the conf-available directory. For example servername.conf.

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf
```

And inside this we just need to add one line

ServerName localhost

I can do that but how do I save it ?

Comment: See [How to exit the VIM editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11828573/4440445)

Comment: You can also use `nano` or `gedit` editor if you don't know how to use `vi` still if you want to use, just follow the answer of steeldriver's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently no-one wants to answer this question, maybe trying to avoid getting into an [editor war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_war)...

You might want to check out [How-To-Geek's Beginner's guide to Vi](https://www.howtogeek.com/102468/a-beginners-guide-to-editing-text-files-with-vi/)

[image]

As it says here, you first have to exit insert mode by pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> and then type `:wq`

w for write and q for quit. Obvious, surely? ;)